# View the scheduled tasks of celery in Django

Tags: django, celery

I am scheduling some tasks with **apply_async()** providing the countdown for the task. Once the tasks execute I can view the state and logs with **django-celery-results**'s **task_results** model. Now, I know all the scheduled tasks are added to the message queue from where I should be able to retrieve the scheduled tasks that haven't executed yet. But is there any other way to view them with state/logs etc? Or will I need to create a model similar to **task_results** and implement the feature myself?